# Python FFT an audio file

Tags: python, fft

I'm trying to plot a magnitude-frequency spectrum from a wav file, the sample rate of the file is 44.1KHz, I only want to compute FFT of the first 100 samples, for that I'm using `np.fft.fft()` However I am getting unexpected results, see image 1.

[image]

I am only getting expected results when I'm computing FFT of at least 2048 samples. why?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def normalizeAudio(data):
    return np.float32((data / max(data)))

SAMPLE_FOR = 1 # in seconds
samplerate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(r'Recording.wav')
data = normalizeAudio(data[0:int(samplerate*SAMPLE_FOR)])


fft_out = np.fft.fft(data[0:100])
freq_vector = np.arange(0, 44100, 44100 / 100)
plt.plot(freq_vector, np.abs(fft_out))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there actually something interesting in the first 100 samples? It's not uncommon for audio files to start with some silence after all

Comment: I see what you mean, is there a way to solve this and still compute FFT of 100? Maybe decimation? @harold

Comment: Also, calculating frequency requires measurement _over time_. The less time you have, the less of the frequency domain you can cover, even if there is in fact something other than silence in that portion of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [librosa](http://librosa.org/doc/main/index.html), it's a very good library for audio analysis in python, including chromatographs, spectograms, percussion graphs and other cool stuff.

It's very well documented with examples and plenty others on stack overflow so I won't copy them here.

Additionally, most applications I've seen tend to use STFT, short-term fourier transform (aka DFT, Discrete Fourier Transform). This is much faster still than plain FFT and more useful for modelling and things to control input shape and also removes a lot of the noise that you can get with FFT as it takes windows rather than instantaneous changes.

Comment: STFT is time series of fourier transforms. FFT is an implementation (supposedly fast) of DFT which is the discreete version of fourier transform. So while one fourier transform (FFT for example) produces a spectrum a STFT produces a spectrogram, a series of spectrums.